# Jquery drag and drop: how to avoid overlapping?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm building a JQuery drag and drop interface and would like that, when an element is dropped, if there is another element above, it arranges automagically to avoid overlap.
Is there a way to do it or do i need additional libraries?

Comment: The [isotope plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) may help you.

Comment: have u tried using drop events of droppable ?? and play with css.. i think that will do the trick..

Comment: I'm trying but the problem is that if i drag the E1 element over the E2 element i would like the E2 elem to automatically move to leave place to E1; if E2 moves over E3 it has to leave space to it and so on ... i hoped to find an already made solution for this. Isotope plugin as suggested seems not handle a absolute layout